# How to get more than 1 ajax call response in different intervals?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

As I'm doing an Ajax call I need to show in front end that what's running in back end.

For Example, I'm uploading a file. At that time I have the following steps to complete.

1. Inserting the file data to DB
2. Moving some of the files to Folder, based on the response from step 1
3. Finally updating the DB

Through a single ajax

- while the *Step 1* running I need to show : *inserting files to DB...*
- in Step 2: *Moving Files to Folder...*
- in Step 3: *Updating the table...*

I know how to get the 3 responses at a time like

```
json_array('res1' => '', 'res2' => '', 'res3' => '')
```

But I need to get the same responses for 3 intervals. Look the below code for your understand

```
function file_sampe_upload(){
    //code for insert
    .......
    echo json_array('status' => 1, 'res1' => 'Files inserted successfully');
   //Code for moving files to specific folder
   ......
   echo json_array('status' => 1, 'res2' => 'Files moved successfully');
   //Code for updating the files
   ......
   echo json_array('status' => 1, 'res3' => 'Files updated successfully');
exit;}
```

Is there any possibility to do like this? Advise is most helpful.

**Update:-**

Is the concept **Outputbuffering** will help full, to this issue?

Comment: Why do you want response in Intervals? You can get all response at same time and execute it at interval

Comment: It will take some time to upload, so i want to update the response in step wise to front end.

Comment: you're most likely going to have to do 3 separate ajax calls

Comment: Well you can use a websocket like Socket.io with Node.js on the application to listen and in PHP for every step accomplished you can send a message, so that the application will know in real time the status

Comment: I need to do it in a single call. Because, after step1 response, step 2 is to be processed. Like this for step3 too

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform 3 AJAX requests for this. So something like this:

```
function file_sampe_insert(){
    echo json_array('status' => 1, 'res1' => 'Files inserted successfully');
    exit;
}

function file_sampe_move(){
    echo json_array('status' => 1, 'res2' => 'Files moved successfully');
    exit;
}

function file_sampe_upload(){
   echo json_array('status' => 1, 'res3' => 'Files updated successfully');
    exit;
}

1. AJAX request which call the insert 
2. AJAX request which call the move
3. AJAX request which call the upload
```

Comment: I need to do it in a single call. Because, using step1 response, step 2 is to be processed. Like this for step3 too

Comment: You can send the response back from step 1 and use that response in your AJAX request for step 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use **WebSockets**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

1. Server PHP:
   http://socketo.me/
2. PHP WebSocket Client: (to send information about the progress)
   https://github.com/lemmingzshadow/php-websocket
3. Javascript Client: (for receiving)
   http://autobahn.ws/js/